# PEAR on Windows: How to change pear.ini location

Tags: php, windows-7, pear

I am trying to install a PEAR package into my recent XAMPP PHP installation (PHP 5.3.1) on Windows 7 64-bit.

Installing new packages fails because PEAR tries to access `c:\windows\pear.ini` instead of the existing `c:\path_to_xampp\php\pear.ini`. This results (rightly) in a `permission denied` error. I am logged on as Administrator, but the Windows directory enjoys some additional protection IIRC.

Rather than fiddle with write rights in the windows directory, I would like to use the existing pear.ini file.

Does anybody know where to change PEAR's behaviour accordingly?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Not entirely sure but PEAR registered the following keys in the registry of my machine

```
REGEDIT4
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment]
"PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR"="D:\\webserver\\xampp\\php"
....
```

And PEAR/Config.php contains the following code snippet:

```
if (getenv('PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR')) {
    define('PEAR_CONFIG_SYSCONFDIR', getenv('PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR'));
```

and the constructor for the Config class

```
function PEAR_Config($user_file = '', $system_file = '', $ftp_file = false,
                         $strict = true)
    {
        $this->PEAR();
        PEAR_Installer_Role::initializeConfig($this);
        $sl = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        if (empty($user_file)) {
            if (OS_WINDOWS) {
                $user_file = PEAR_CONFIG_SYSCONFDIR . $sl . 'pear.ini';
            } else {
                $user_file = getenv('HOME') . $sl . '.pearrc';
            }
        }
```

`$user_file = PEAR_CONFIG_SYSCONFDIR . $sl . 'pear.ini';` seems to be the line that makes "my" PEAR installation use the file D:\webserver\xampp\php\pear.ini.
If that's correct all you have to do is to somehow set the environment variable `PEAR_CONFIG_SYSCONFDIR`

Comment: Cheers Volker! `PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR` it is.

Comment: Works beautifully for a global PEAR install. But if there are multiple local PEARs, you need to patch pear.bat. See here for more:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10219809/508355

Answer (score 10):

Another way is edit your windows system environment and add PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR variable pointing to php's dir.

Comment: On Windows, edit your pear.bat to have the line `IF "%PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR%"=="" SET "PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR=c:\dev\php"` (or pointing to wherever your PHP installation actually is)

Answer (score 3):

To change the path from `c:\windows\pear.ini` to `c:\path_to_xampp\php\pear.ini` you can download this file at http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar and place it in your `c:\path_to_xampp\php`  folder.
Run:

> php go-pear.phar

Change the location of your pear.ini (11) to `c:\path_to_xampp\php` (`$prefix\pear.ini`).
Save and run the new file `c:\path_to_xampp\php\PEAR_ENV.reg`.
Log out of Windows and run (in `c:\path_to_xampp\php`)

> pear config-show

Now you can see that the path has been updated :)

Comment: Your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27434425/bitbucket-permission-denied-publickey-fatal-the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpect could have benefited other. No need to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

In windows 7 i use powershell.

you can set the PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR variable and then run a pear command. For Example:

```
$env:PEAR_CONFIG_SYSCONFDIR = 'c:\path_to_xampp\php'
pear install pear.phpunit.de/PHPUnit
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks user2204085 !
To be more accurate, when you run

```
 php go-pear.phar
```

type 11 (not 'all' or not enter) then type `$prefix\pear.ini` . 
The file PEAR_ENV.reg will be created in your php directory. 
I've followed the above steps, and it works fine for me.`enter code here`