# PEAR directory problem on Windows

Tags: php, windows, pear

I've downloaded the ZIP archive of PHP and extracted it under my profile. I then needed some PEAR packages. `go-pear.bat` apparently installed PEAR just fine, I just needed to go into the `pear.bat` file afterwards and adapt the path to `php.exe` – no big deal and after that it ran.

However, when I try installing something I get the following error:

> ERROR: failed to mkdir C:\php5\pear\data\Console_CommandLine\data

Naturally, no write access is allowed in the root directory but I'm a little at a loss to know how exactly PEAR thinks it should install anything in a location that neither exists nor is configured anywhere. PHP currently resides somewhere below `H:\` (subst'ed to my profile). All paths I entered during PEAR installation were sane and the only place I can find `C:\php5` is in `PEAR/go-pear.phar` and in the documentation. One of those is something I shouldn't change anyway, I guess and the other thing is hardly relevant for the program itself.

Now, I probably could go in and make `C:\php5` a junction/symlink to the directory where PHP lies currently or actually install it in that location – both things I'd rather avoid since this was originally just intended for a little test of something.

I since looked into `pear help install` and apparently I can use `-P` or `-R` so set some paths. The exact difference between those is still unclear to me but it won't hurt to try them, I guess. Somehow the results were ... unexpected:

`-P H:\Downloads\php\PEAR` resulted in the fun error (among others)

> ERROR: failed to mkdir C:\Downloads\php\PEAR\php5\pear\data\Console_CommandLine\data

while `-R` using the same path (apparently `-R` dictates where downloads are stored, since that worked before I guess I shouldn't touch this) resulted in even more fun:

> download directory "C:\Downloads\php\PEAR\Users\JOHANN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pear\download" is not writeable.  Change download_dir config variable to a writeable dir

By now I guess both `C:\` and `php5` are somewhere hardcoded for no apparent reason (my environment variables also contain nothing of that sort) so I'll go digging again, this time looking for shorter string and therefore longer result lists.

But if anyone has an idea about this in the meantime, this might be helpful.

Answer (score 19):

The problem is that PEAR looks for its ini file in the Windows directory, and because it doesn't find it there, it resorts to guessing the location. Even worse, you can't change any configuration settings with `pear config-set` because PEAR doesn't have a pear.ini to write to. At the same time, PEAR ignores an existing pear.ini file in its own directory. It's a mess. See this [bug report](http://pear.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=16939).

If there is just one global PEAR install, PEAR can be told where to look for an ini file by creating an environment variable, `PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR`, pointing to the right directory.

But if there are multiple, local PEAR installs, you'll have to patch pear.bat by adding this line:

`IF "%PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR%"=="" SET "PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR=C:\path\to\pear.ini\directory"`

Comment: @hashchange What line should this be added to the bat file?

Comment: @rrrfusco Line 28, in my installs. More generally, in the section titled "Check PEAR global ENV, set them if they do not exist".

Answer (score 3):

A slightly better option than [michael h's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10219809/629493) might be:

1. Open `$prefix\pear\PEAR\Config.php` where `$prefix` is the value used in the PEAR installer. (On my Windows system, `$prefix` was `C:\php\5.4.0`)
2. Find the section below:

   ```
   if (getenv('PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR')) {
       define('PEAR_CONFIG_SYSCONFDIR', getenv('PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR'));
   } elseif (getenv('SystemRoot')) {
       define('PEAR_CONFIG_SYSCONFDIR', getenv('SystemRoot'));
   } else {
       define('PEAR_CONFIG_SYSCONFDIR', PHP_SYSCONFDIR);
   }
   ```
3. And make the following changes:

   ```
   if (getenv('PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR')) {
       define('PEAR_CONFIG_SYSCONFDIR', getenv('PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR'));
   //} elseif (getenv('SystemRoot')) {
       //define('PEAR_CONFIG_SYSCONFDIR', getenv('SystemRoot'));
   } else {
       //define('PEAR_CONFIG_SYSCONFDIR', PHP_SYSCONFDIR);

       // This next line is new
       define('PEAR_CONFIG_SYSCONFDIR', $PEAR_INSTALL_DIR);
   }
   ```

This solution is less hazard-prone when dealing with multiple PHP/PEAR versions/installations, especially when running more than one at the same time, as you avoid environment clobbering.

Apparently the PEAR developers overlooked the fact that `WINDOWS`, `Program Files` and friends have been deprecated as application-data directories since Windows Vista, and are generally no longer writable by non-elevated applications. (For good security reasons.)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `config-...` parameters of the PEAR command:

```
config-create          Create a Default configuration file
config-get             Show One Setting
config-help            Show Information About Setting
config-set             Change Setting
config-show            Show All Settings
```

I presume `C:\php5` is the builtin default directory when you don't set another one.

Comment: Looks promising, `config-show` yields quite a lot settings that point to `C:\php5\something`. Now I just need to figure out how I can tell PEAR to use a sane location for the configuration file. Expecting a *user* config file in `C:\Windows` is probably the weirdest thing I've seen in a while.

Comment: Ok, solved it now. Running `pear` from a subdirectory of `C:\` and giving a path on the `C:` drive to the `-P` option worked, apparently.

Answer (score 2):

you can specify the config file via

```
pear -c /path/to/config/file $command
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem. My config file was missing from the `C:\Windows` directory - there is definitely something wrong with the go-pear installer - I specified a different `INI` file location, yet my wish has not come true.

I copied `pear.ini` to `C:\windows` and everything started to work.

Answer (score 1):

If your PHP installation has been done somewhere else other than the C:\ drive, then “pear install” command may throw errors.

Example: Here in my case, the xampp has been installed into E:\ drive and the “pear install” throws error.

[Error got when I run the command. This also happen for PHPDocumentor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8hpM.png)
Solution:
I get into the “pear” directory and checked config values set for different pear related directories. All were set to C:\ drive by default. So, we need to change those settings to correct path.
Open the command prompt in "Run as administrator" mode.

[Pear default setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYU7P.png)
Now change five path in xampp like this

```
E:\xampp\php>
E:\xampp\php>pear config-set doc_dir E:\xampp\php\pear
```

If you are using C drive and getting the same error then also the above statement will remain same just replace the drive name E:\ to C:\ vice versa.
example for C: drive

```
C:\xampp\php>pear config-set doc_dir C:\xampp\php\pear
```

Then press enter it will display a msg of **config-set succeeded**

Like this you have to enter 5 commands.

```
E:\xampp\php>pear config-set doc_dir E:\xampp\php\pear
```

config-set succeeded

```
E:\xampp\php>pear config-set cfg_dir E:\xampp\php\pear
```

config-set succeeded

```
E:\xampp\php>pear config-set data_dir E:\xampp\php\pear
```

config-set succeeded

```
E:\xampp\php>pear config-set test_dir E:\xampp\php\pear
```

config-set succeeded

```
E:\xampp\php>pear config-set www_dir E:\xampp\php\pear
```

config-set succeeded

[Finally installed pear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiL5o.png)