# PEAR & PHPUnit on Windows 7 with WAMP

Tags: php, phpunit, pear, wamp

I know there are several threads on this already, but I've hit a brick wall and can't find any threads with the same issue I now have. In a nutshell, my problem is that PEAR's config is still set to the C:\Windows directory, where it always (correctly) fails due to permissions. I've added System environment variables as follows, so I don't know why these seem to be getting ignored:

```
PHP_PEAR_BIN_DIR=C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.4
PHP_PEAR_DATA_DIR=C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.4\PEAR\data
PHP_PEAR_DOC_DIR=C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.4\PEAR\docs
PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR=C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.4\pear
PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN=C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.4\php.exe
PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR=C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.4
PHP_PEAR_TEST_DIR=C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.4\PEAR\tests
```

typical error is

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.4>pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
PEAR_Config::writeConfigFile fopen('C:\Windows\pear.ini','w') failed (fopen(C:\Windows\pear.ini): failed to open stream:
 Permission denied)
```

My initial install commands were as follows:

```
php -d phar.require_hash=0 PEAR/go-pear.phar
pear channel-discover pear.phpunit.de
pear channel-discover components.ez.no
pear channel-discover pear.symfony-project.com
pear install phpunit/PHPUnit
```

I've tried removing the install and starting from scratch, but still no dice. Anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: @Gordon - thanks, will try this now - how exactly do I relog to my account? That may well be the issue.

Comment: @Gordon - yep that did it, logged out and back in and all good now. Can't believe that's all it was :) Can you add an answer so that I can mark it solved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to update your PEAR installation by requesting http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar in your browser and save the output to a local file go-pear.phar; then run php go-pear.phar from the CLI. This will let you reconfigure the paths and IIRC it will also create a reg file you can simply doubleclick to import the environment variables.

Also make sure to relog to your account when adding environment variables.

Answer (score 4):

Try to change the ini location modifying some entries in the registry

according to this question

[PEAR on Windows: How to change pear.ini location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2180197/pear-on-windows-how-to-change-pear-ini-location)

You can find the location of the "sysconf" here and alter it

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment]
"PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR"="D:\\webserver\\xampp\\php"
```

Comment: Even nicer than my answer, +1 :) Good to know thats possible too

Comment: @VAShhh - I don't have that entry in the registry under [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment] - should it be manually added?

Comment: http://trac.symfony-project.org/wiki/HowToInstallPearOnWindowsWithWamp here you can see that PEAR_ENV.reg is situated in the wamp/php folder, try to modify the file and add it to the registry